# Delaying execution - C# WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, timer, delayed-execution

I have a Grid control and clicking on each row does some background job to load the data. Each background job is performed on a thread pool thread. When user clicks on the items quickly, lot of requests to load data will be queued. I want to minimize this by providing a delay after clicking each row. There will be some delay before firing the request to load the data.

I am thinking about using [DispatcherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx) class. Something like,

```
readonly DispatcherTimer dt = new DispatcherTimer();
private void Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    dt.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);
    dt.Stop();
    dt.Start();
}

private void DtOnTick(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    // Fire a thread and do data loading
}
```

Is this the correct way to approach the problem?

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: I would think it would be more correct to aggregate the results of the background operations and, if necessary, delay updating the bound data source in the aggregation process. Is the problem that you don't want the user to see lots of updates?

Comment: Or is the problem that you are hitting the database for each click and want to combine the individual queries?

Comment: The background job does lot of COM calls and I don't want that to happen always.

Answer (score 1):

How about disabling the control until the job is finished? Or disabling once the queue of jobs to do reaches a certain size? This would be a simple solution to prevent users from "clicking too much". And this way the delay would scale with the efficiency of your solution/speed of the computer.

Answer (score 1):

The way you're trying to do it would just delay the problem itself for 2 seconds. All the clicks would just be handled two seconds later.

You might try to use a worker thread. Lets say you use a queue which takes information about each item that was clicked at the time it was clicked. An existing thread, created when the class is created, is notified when new items are added to the queue. The thread takes the first item, processes it, updates the UI. If there are more items, it takes the next one, processes it, etc. When there are no more items, the thread goes to sleep until new items are available (`ManualResetEvent` will help here).

The pattern would be:

```
void ItemClicked(...) 
{
    lock (WorkQueue)
    {
        QueueNewClickItem(...);
        m_workToDo.Set();
    }
}


void WorkerThread(...)
{
    bool threadShouldEnd = false;
    while (!threadShouldEnd)
    {
        if (WaitHandle.WaitAny(m_workToDo, m_endThread) == 0)
        {
           lock (WorkQueue)
           {
               CopyAllPendingWorkItemsToListInThread();
               ClearWorkQueue();
               m_workToDo.Reset();
           }

           while (!AllLocalItemsProcessed)
           {
               ProcessNextWorkItem();
           }
        }
        else
        {
            threadShouldEnd = true;
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: But not all clicks are processed. Only the last click will be processed after the specified delay.

Comment: From your question I thought you had to handle every single click, but wanted to process them one after the other. If you only want to handle the last click, you should go for the timer thing: When a click occurs, start a timer. If another click occurrs before the timer fires, reset the timer. If the timer fires, perform the action common to all clicks.

Answer (score 0):

What you actually want to do is something like this:

```
private DateTime? _NextAllowedClick;

private void Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   if (_NextAllowedClick != null && DateTime.Now < _NextAllowedClick)
   {
      return;
   }
   _NextAllowedClick = DateTime.Now + new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 2);
   ...
}
```